# How can I reconfigure the nvidia proprietary drivers from the command line (ssh)?

Tags: nvidia

I have a linux HTPC (running XBMC) in my living room.

This morning I ssh'ed into the machine and did upgrade it to 10.10. When it finaly resarted it says something about running in low quality graphics and eventually returned to a command line login prompt. I ssh'ed in again and did a `sudo reboot now`. When it came back on this time the image is rapidly scrolling from the top to the bottom of the screen. I guess the installed driver doesn't quite work with the S-Video port on which the TV is connected.

previously it was working right with the nvidia proprietary drivers. How can I install thoses without using the GUI tool that comes with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`nvidia-xconfig` will write a new default configuration file.  You can then test it from there.  If you need to edit the new file it will be located under `/etc/X11`

To install the drivers is `sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx-xxx`  where xxx is the version whether it is 96, 173,185 depending on your card.

Comment: Tanks Casey, I suppose I'll have to install some package to get the drivers. Anyone know which package?

Comment: Just added that part.  Sorry I left it out.  You may also want to check out Nvtv TV Out to help you finetune the S-Video

Answer (score 21):

[jockey](https://launchpad.net/jockey) is the tool used in Ubuntu to manage 3rd party drivers, particularly proprietary ones like the Nvidia drivers. In addition to the gui tool, it has a text based utility for manipulating drivers as well, `jockey-text` from the `jockey-common` package. To list what drivers jockey thinks are available for your hardware use  `jockey-text --list`; e.g.:

```
jockey-text --list
```

returns (on my system with an ATI graphics chipset):

`xorg:fglrx - ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)`

To then enable it, do `sudo jockey-text -e DRIVER`, thus in my case, to enable the fglrx driver, I'd do `sudo jockey-text -e xorg:fglrx`.

See `jockey-text --help` for more information (sadly, there doesn't appear to be a man page for it).

Comment: ubuntu-drivers replaces jockey tool for the new Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have nvidia driver installed and I solves this issue with

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```