# Removing all traces of Nvidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia, ati, kubuntu, catalyst

Changed my hardware from Nvidia to AMD in PC pretty much for gaming on my windows install. But now i have booted back into Ubuntu and its taking a hissy fit at the change of hardware.

I want to remove all types of drivers, X11 configs, EVERYTHING. Then start from scratch. I have been un-installing and reinstalling drivers for past couple of days with no luck of getting catalyst running successfully.

Any help would be great thanks alot.

Bill

Comment: If no nvidia hardware is present it shouldn't be loading nvidia stuff, i did the same and never had a problem installing catalyst, now if you want to remove the nvidia drivers search for them using `apt-cache search nvidia-*` or use Synaptic and search for nvidia then uninstall.

Comment: This question is about going the other way round, the answers might help nonetheless: [Uninstalling ATI's drivers and installing Nvidia's?](http://askubuntu.com/q/25528)

Comment: I found that last night mate thanks. Will update my question with how i did it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here goes on how I fixed this.

After uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers multiple times, it wouldn't successfully install the catalyst drivers without some form of issues.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

This removed all the AMD drivers or what was left from previous installs.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

Both of these commands then removed what I had from Nvidia drivers.

I then rebooted and instead of installing the AMD drivers from apt-get I used the additional drivers in the system menu. They installed fine and i rebooted again. And boom! They were there.

The thing was I had tried using the additional drivers option before only for it to fail. but not to bother it worked and im now using the latest drivers. I made a complete hash of this one and its not a great solution but a solution nevertheless.

Thanks
Bill