# how to reset dual display to one screen from command line?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, xorg, display

How can I reset dual display to one screen from command line and set old second screen as main display? (12.04 + nvidia)

Comment: see [this question on a similar topic](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6521/how-can-i-reconfigure-the-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-from-the-command-line-ssh), and the docs for [NvidiaMultiMonitors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors) and [DynamicMultiMonitor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicMultiMonitor).

Comment: you'd probably want to check out the [`nvidia-xconfig` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/alt-nvidia-96-xconfig.1.html) as well. it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

In 18.04 and earlier I would recommend installing [disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/), a command line display manager.

Then you can do `disper -S` to make secondary only, or `disper -e -t left` to extend to the left for example.