# Additional Drivers not found now that I have switched Motherbaords

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-settings

So, long story short my Asus P8Z77-v Pro died on Sunday (the second one I've had die) so I got myself an AsRock P77 Extreme4 to tide me over/replace it.

Problem is that when I goto install my NVIDIA Proprietary Drivers Ubuntu cannot find any. The 'Additional Drivers' searches and finds nothing.

I have Downloaded the Latest directly from NVIDIA to try a manual install tonight but I'd rather have this simple and useful feature work. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

Side note: I used the same Flash disk to install 13.10 and everything else seems to work, even the 2 displays coming off of this gfx card, just not using decent drivers that support OpenGL etc...

Thanks,

Comment: Only difference between this system and what I had before Sunday is the Mainboard. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after many failed attempts with varying results I have FIXED this problem. I at one point managed to get my NVIDIA drivers installed manually whilst breaking half of Ubuntu. It did however work well enough to login running the proprietary drivers so I knew it would work.

Annoyingly the eventual solution was rather simple, annoying since it's taken all my free time this week when I could have fixed it in 3 minutes.

### The Fix

After a fresh install of 13.10 do the following:

```
jockey-text -l
```

Shows a list of drivers that **should** show up in the Additional Drivers menu option. Then I ran the 'activation' for the top item:

```
sudo jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_319_updates
```

2 minutes later and BAM it worked!

It still fails to find additional drivers in the system settings menu, or even show that I am currently running one. But this is definitely fixed! :)

Thanks to:

[How can I reconfigure the nvidia proprietary drivers from the command line (ssh)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6521/how-can-i-reconfigure-the-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-from-the-command-line-ssh)

Useful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1741754

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744248

Comment: That's just frustratingly simple. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Indeed! With a clear head I looked at the problem differently, not how do I install the drivers manually, instead how do I fix/workaround jockey.

Comment: jockey-common is now surpassed by ubuntu-drivers in 14.04. I have logged a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310568

Comment: Now fixed in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to directly install nvidia-current package from the repository. You can also try

```
apt-get update --fix-missing
```

to fix any repository mismatches, in case that happened and that's why the additional driver software can't find you the driver you want.

Comment: Just tried that, no errors on install. But now after grub I get a black low res screen and a cursor, that's all seems it's more than just a missing driver. Thanks though that is useful to know!

Comment: And recovery mode to autoremove nvidia-current give two full res screens but both black and with a cross as the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem on Ubuntu 14.04 by installing the xorg-edgers ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
```

The drivers now show up under the additional drivers tab.

You can determine which driver to install by visiting 
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx and filling in the details about your graphics card and system.

Comment: This was fixed in later versions for me, plus since I have switched to manually installing them. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-nvidia-346-35-ubuntu-1404/